# How to solve this initial value separable differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\mathrm y' = {2x\over 1+2y} \;\; , \; y(2) = 0$$

So far, I have $${dy\over dx}(1 + 2y) = 2x$$

$$  1+ 2y\,dy = 2x\,dx $$
$$ \int 1+2y\,dy = \int 2x\,dx  $$
$$ y + y^2 = x^2 + C$$

However, from $ y + y^2 = x^2 + C $, I'm not sure how to arrive to the solution, which is

given as $ y = -{1\over 2} + {1\over 2} \sqrt{4x^2 - 15} $

Comment: Set $x=2$ and $y=0$ to get $C$, then solve for $y$ using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next, use the initial condition.  When $x=2$, $y=0$.  So, plugging in, you have $0=2^2+C$ shows $C=-4$.  Thus, your equation is $y+y^2=x^2-4$.  Completing the square on the LHS, you have $\left(y+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = x^2-4+\dfrac{1}{4} = x^2-\dfrac{15}{4}$

Hence, $y = -\dfrac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{x^2-\dfrac{15}{4}} = -\dfrac{1}{2}\pm \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{4x^2-15}$

Next, plug in $x=2$ and see if you get zero:

$y(2) = -\dfrac{1}{2}\pm \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{1} = 0$, so the $\pm$ can only be plus.